# Not able to import matplotlib

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, raspberry-pi

I am trying image analysis on the Raspberry Pi using opencv and python. For this I am using the two commands

```
source ~/.profile
workon cv
```

before doing the work. I don't really understand what these does but I can only import the opencv into python after these two steps. As far as I can tell, this makes the work in a cv environment. In this environment, when I try to import matplotlib, its showing that the module does not exist. But I have installed the module and its working fine outside the cv environment. How do I get the matplotlib to work even after I have executed the the previous commands? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on [python virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) (and you also are using the additional [virtualenvwrapper tools](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), read about them next), but basically what is going on here is that you have the `opencv` package installed in a virtual environment (called `cv`) but you don't have `matplotlib` installed there as well. You can fix this by, after typing `workon cv`, install `matplotlib`:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried that but its returning an error with a lot of red lines. At the end, it mentions MemoryError. I am guessing this means I am running out of time space? I tried uninstalling matplotlib outside the cv environment to free some space but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know much about running python on an r-pi.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pip --no-cache-dir install matplotlib` to fix Memory Error Problems